# VCL Styles possible bug with drawing scrollbars

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles, tpagecontrol

I have a pagecontrol in the center of my main form (form1 in my image), and I want to open other forms docked into the pagecontrol. Because I have many controls on my child form, I need both vertical and horizontal scrollbars (on the child form I have active scrollbars option active), but here is the catch: when I use VCL Styles, my scrollbars aren't drawing as they should be and they are unusable. Is this some kind of a bug of VCL Styles?

[image]

Comment: I there are some bugs with scrollbars in new VCL Styles.

Comment: If you haven't already, you might want to vist [The Road to Delphi](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/), as there is a lot of information about VCL Styles there

Comment: Can you provide a basic code to replicate the issue?

Comment: @RRUZ - Basic code for the problem: In 'OnCreate' of the form put `AutoScroll:=False;`, `VertScrollBar.Range:=Height*2;` The scrollbar shows only with 'Windows' theme.

Comment: so i will try yo explain in a few words: on my main form i have a button which triggers the creation of my child form(the one that i want to dock into the page control); this is the code that i wrote on TMainFormCreateButton.Click :`if not Assigned (Form2) then  Form2:= TForm2.Create (Application);`
  `Form2.ManualDock(PageControl1);`
  `Form2.Show;` if i don`t have vcl styles enabled it all works fine, but with a vcl style active, the scrollbar om my child form doesn`t draw correctly :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scrollbars ([`TControlScrollBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TControlScrollBar)) used by the TForm doesn't support the Vcl Styles (you must report this to the [QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx) page), if you want fix that you must override that control and paint the scrollbars using the Vcl styles methods, but that will requiere a lot of work, as simple workround you can use the [`TScrollBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TScrollBar) component (in your form) which properly supports the vcl styles.

Comment: @Rodrigo: but if i use the method that you used at TWebBrowser project in your blog, it could work? i will give it a try and let you know ;)

Comment: I think I found a way, not very nice but it did work. On the child form I have placed a TScrollBox and set it`s Align Property= AllClient; and then in my TScrollBox i`ve added all my components that i am supposed to use; and at runtime scrolling works ;)